# MINGW64 doesn't print during execution

Tags: python, windows, shell, console, mingw-w64

I'm using [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) to run my Python scripts on Windows. I noticed that the console doesn't print while my scripts are running. All the strings are printed just when the scripts finish. I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230774/2684718) that is a buffer and line break issue. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this including `sys.stdout.flush()` after each `print()`.

Comment: I'm using freshly installed Windows 10, git bash and `Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)` and I don't see anything printed even after flushing or causing an error. Works fine at `cmd`, any suggestions on how to get it to work in Mingw64? `python -u` doesn't help either, I'm not seeing even `>>>` at line beginning.

Answer (score 6):

I am using MINGW64 on Windows10, and `python -u` works for me. For example,

```
   python -u foo.py
```

From `python --help`:

> ```
> -u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
>          see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'
> ```